# Git branching is not working properly

Tags: git, bash, branch

We just discovered this issue and several of us are replicating the behavior. We suspect we're missing some arguments but we really don't know what's up.

When we branch and then make a new file in the branch, it shows up in the master.

We run this code to replicate the issue:

```
mkdir test ; cd test ; git init ; touch test1 ; git add test1 ; git commit -m "test 1" ; git branch new ; git checkout new ; touch test2 ; git checkout master
```

Here's what I got when I ran it:

```
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:Desktop mikeghen$ mkdir test ; cd test ; git init ; touch test1 ; git add test1 ; git commit -m "test 1" ; git branch new ; git checkout new ; touch test2 ; git checkout master
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/mikeghen/Desktop/test/.git/
[master (root-commit) 231a738] test 1
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test1
Switched to branch 'new'
Switched to branch 'master'
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:test mikeghen$ ls
test1   test2
```

Let me know if anyone knows why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: shot in the dark, but maybe it's because the file is empty? I don't think empty files are tracked by git. try putting something in the file and seeing what happens.

Comment: @eriese It's because, in git, uncommited changes float between branches. Theres a nice blog post in Gergo Erdosi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncommitted changes are not discarded when you switch branches. If you want to discard local changes, then either stash them (for later use):

```
git stash changes
```

or reset the working directory:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

You can read more about it in [this](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/switching-branches-without-committing/) blog post.